# Generate Coupon code based on category

Tags: coupon, coupon-codes

I need to sent an coupon code while new user registration. 
coupon code i based on category and its valid for one month. How to generate the coupon code in registration page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can find here](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/2010/04/create-bulk-discount-rules.html) a script that will generate a coupon code.
An other approach you could take is to create a coupon code in the backend and just put a debug code inside `Mage_Adminhtml_Promo_QuoteController::saveAction` to see how the data sent through post looks like.
Add this

```
Mage::log($data, null, 'discount.log', true);
```

right before `$model->loadPost($data);`.
Then check the file `var/log/discount.log`.
You should find there how the structure of the coupon data should look like.

Then create an observer for the `customer_register_success` where you build an array that has the same structure as what is contained in the log file and do this:

```
$data = ...;//build your array here
$model = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');
$model->loadPost($data);
$model->save();
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply. Where to set category id?. I need to set the rules based on the particular categories for newly register customer ( For example , i want to tshirt and pant category only).

Comment: You need to set the categories in the conditions section. Take the second approach I added and create a coupon for the category you want and see how the array sent through post looks like.

Comment: hi, where is the second approach. i didn't find the code because I'm new for magento .

Comment: Hi Marius, Thanks for your post. Its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a code to be sent in the same email as the registration confirmation, you can extend the customer class and add a custom method getMyCoupon() with the logic described in Marius' answer.

Then in the email jus use 
{{var customer.getMyCoupon()}}